# Allow admin to create new columns/tables in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration

I have a number of record types (i.e. forms) within a Rails app that I've migrated to the db while developing e.g. "Request" (name of requestor, description of request) etc. This Request record can now store the information typed in - standard stuff.

I would like this app to be flexible and not require me to go back to the code and run a migration every time a new field needs to be added.

I want to give admin users the rights to create new fields on a record type - for example, adding a due_date field. I cannot find any way to do this without access to the command line to run `rails generate model`...

In addition, is it possible to also give admin users a way to create new record types - e.g. a "Project" record that can then have custom fields added to it as above.

(In C/libpq I would have just sent `CREATE TABLE`... commands to the database and then used column/type names to construct a form - but I'm pretty sure that I'd break Rails' MVC pretty badly doing that).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys who created Lokomotive cms, have implemented such features with MongoDB: http://locomotivecms.com/features.

So, I suggest you to look at MongoDB and Mongoid and decide, can you accomplish your goals with such tools.

Comment: I had a look at MongoDB and that reading got me onto CouchDB which I think I like better. I've played with Couch and Mongo a little bit now and I think that a NoSQL-style DB is the way to go for this project. Halfway through a Ruby + Rails + CouchDB screencast at the moment - looks like it fits the bill. - Thanks so much! I've accepted your answer.